# When I create a csv, from a data frame in Python, a new column is added to the beginning of the table in my csv. How do I remove this column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

[image: CSV Table]

How do I remove the first column in the table below, in Python, which is created when I generate a csv from a data frame in Python? Or is there a way to prevent this first column from being created in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [pandas.to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), there is the `index` param setted True by default. This means that it will write a column for the index.

If you want to prevent index writing, you have to set it to false:

```py
df.to_csv(your_path, index=False)
```